# XML huge file processing

Tags: python, xml, python-3.6

Here, i need to fetch and print the values of source, destination ip address only if action = accept
The path it needs to navigate through (to capture value from xml file is) -

```
<edge>
 <features> 
  <firewall>- 
     <firewallRules>
        <firewallRule> 
         action = accept
         <source>
           <ipAddress>169.25</ipAddress> (need this)
           <ipAddress>169.25</ipAddress> (need this
         </source>
         <destination>
           <ipAddress>169.25</ipAddress>(need this)
           <ipAddress>169.25</ipAddress>(need this)
         </destination>
         </firewallRule>
         <firewallRule>
             ------ 
         </firewallRule> 
         <firewallRule>   
          -------                   
         </firewallRule>
      </features>                                                           
    </edge>
```

my xml file

```
<edge>
 <enableAesni>true</enableAesni>
 <enableFips>true</enableFips>
 <vseLogLevel>debug</vseLogLevel>
   <defaultPolicy>
      <action>deny</action>
   </defaultPolicy>
 <features>
   <firewall>
     <version>40</version>
     <enabled>true</enabled>
     <globalConfig>
        <tcpPickOngoingConnections>false</tcpPickOngoingConnections>
        <enableFtpLooseMode>false</enableFtpLooseMode>
     </globalConfig>
     <defaultPolicy>
        <action>deny</action>
        <loggingEnabled>true</loggingEnabled>
     </defaultPolicy> 
     <firewallRules>
        <firewallRule>
           <id>131074</id>
           <description>highAvailability</description>
           <action>accept</action>
           <source>
              <exclude>false</exclude>
              <ipAddress>169.25</ipAddress>
              <ipAddress>169.25</ipAddress>
           </source>
           <destination>
              <exclude>false</exclude>
              <ipAddress>169.25</ipAddress>
              <ipAddress>169.25</ipAddress>
              <ipAddress>224.81</ipAddress>
           </destination>
        </firewallRule>
        <firewallRule>
           <id>131078</id>
           <ruleTag>131078</ruleTag>
           <name>firewall</name>
           <action>accept</action>
           <source>
              <exclude>false</exclude>
              <vnicGroupId>vse</vnicGroupId>
           </source>
        </firewallRule>
        <firewallRule>
           <id>137227</id>
           <ruleTag>137227</ruleTag>
           <name>test_sbbdcn</name>
          <action>accept</action>
           <source>
              <exclude>false</exclude>
              <ipAddress>158.87</ipAddress>
           </source>
           <destination>
              <exclude>false</exclude>
              <ipAddress>149.131</ipAddress>
           </destination>
           <application>
              <applicationId>application-57</applicationId>
              <applicationId>application-105</applicationId>
           </application>
        </firewallRule>
</features>
   <type>gatewayServices</type>
   <isUniversal>false</isUniversal>
   <hypervisorAssist>false</hypervisorAssist>
   <tunnels />
```

The code i wrote but failed to navigate through the desired path and fetch value.

```
import os
from xml.etree import ElementTree
file_name= 'sa1fwir01mci.xml'
full_file = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(file_name))
print(full_file)
dom = ElementTree.parse(full_file)
root = dom.getroot()
print(root)
for node in root:
    tag = node.tag
    attribute = node.attrib
    #print(tag , attribute)
    if tag == 'features':
        for ab in node.iter('firewallRules'):
            print(ab.text)
```

Need assistance on how i can achieve the desired value from xml file. refer the path for clarity.
I need to fetch and print the values of source, destination ip address only if action = accept (from path mentioned above)

Comment: Upload a VALID xml file - the current one is not valid.

Comment: Someone please help

Comment: Can you update your question with what you would like to have for output?

Comment: I need to capture IP address from source and destination
It should iterate through all firewall rule tag and only if action = accept, it should take values of ip address from source and destination , from above example it should display 
"169.25
169.25
169.25
169.25"
4 times , first 2 values from source and 2 values from destination since action = accept. @ColeTierney

Comment: There's no point telling us the file is "huge" unless the size actually matters, and we can only tell if the size matters if you give us some numbers.

Comment: Your xml sample is not well formed, but it is if you replace `</features>` with `</firewallRules></firewall>`. That should be good enough for us to experiment with.

Comment: I have edited my code and added the missed tag<features>, hope it makes sense now @ColeTierney

Comment: Look at the elementtree documenation for the xpath support - you can use `findall()` with a path like `“.//action[.=‘accept’]/..”` to find the firewallRule element, then use `findall()` on that element with a path like `”.//ipAddress”` to get the ipAddress elements, you can use `.text` on those elements to get the address. https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html?highlight=xpath%20support

Answer (score 0):

I understand you're looking for a python solution, but here's how it can be done using xslt and an xsl template on the command line with `xsltproc`. You can use the contents of firewall.xsl as a string in python.

firewall.xsl:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="//firewallRule[
        action/text() = 'accept'
    ]">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="source|destination"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="source|destination">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ipAddress"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ipAddress">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
        <xsl:text>&#x0a;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- override default built-in text() template -->
    <xsl:template match="text()" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

command:

```sh
xsltproc firewall.xsl source.xml
```

Source can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/putnamhill/9bf35720bec0bc60a6e4a79d310e058e)